# How to use __FILE__ inside qx?

Tags: perl, qx

I'm trying to assign a constant at the top of a Perl script like so:

```
use constant {
  # ...
  CONSTNAME => qx{readlink -e __FILE__} || __FILE__,
  # ...
};
```

`__FILE__` does not get interpolated inside the `qx` operator, which causes this to fail. How can I achieve what I want, which is to interpolate the `__FILE__` *before* calling `readlink` of the shell.

Please note: it is not an option to store the command inside an intermediate variable in between.

Comment: @TLP: are they always going to contain the identical value on all platforms?

Comment: @TLP or the standard [`FindBin` module](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html)

Comment: @Andy: "standard" implying that it is core Perl?

Comment: Yes, standard meaning core perl, at least back to 5.004 according to http://search.cpan.org/~chips/perl5.004/

Comment: Why can't you use temporaries?

Comment: @Greg : coding style forbids.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer the question directly, you can use the interpolate-arbitrary-expression-in-string idiom described in [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html):

```
print qx{echo @{[ __FILE__ ]}};
```

A couple caveats raised in the comments:

- The `[]` supplies list context. That doesn't matter here, but is worth being aware of in general.
- You can get in trouble if `__FILE__` has shell metacharacters.

If your goal is to find the path of your perl script with all symlinks resolved, you may want to look at the [`FindBin` module](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html). `FindBin` has been part of the core perl distribution for some time (at least since 5.004 according to http://search.cpan.org/~chips/perl5.004/).

Comment: @Andy: thanks. Learned something new today. And special thanks for the swift answer. Going to accept as soon as I can.

Comment: *Be careful though: square brackets supply list context to their expression.  In this case it doesn't matter, but when it does, use an explicit `scalar` to force the context: `say "mysub returns @{ [scalar mysub(1,2,3)] } now."`* — slight paraphrasal from **Programming Perl, 3rd edition**, page 259.

Comment: @hobbs I agree that this should be used sparingly. I considered less complimentary words before settling on "idiom"; perlref calls it "chicanery".

Comment: @tchrist: or the special scalar function call syntax: `~~mysub(...)`  (just kidding)

Comment: @Andy: I think you should add the FindBin reference to your actual answer (or add another answer). It turns out that's the easiest and apparently also the safest (shell meta characters) solution overall. I.e.: `$FindBin::RealBin` ... I wish I could upvote twice. This was a real life saver.

Answer (score 2):

An all-Perl solution:

```
my $self = $0;
while( -l $self ){
  $self = readlink $self;
}
use constant {
  # ...
  CONSTNAME => $self,
  # ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I'd like to avoid any variables before the constants simply because of the coding style. Still +1 as it would work without that restriction.

Answer (score 2):

Use `readpipe` the function equivalent of `qx//`. Internal to Perl `qx//` mostly behaves like `qq//` and then passes the result to `readpipe`. When the quoting behavior of `qx//` gets in the way you can bypass it and call `readpipe` directly.

```
use constant {
    CONSTNAME => readpipe('readlink -e ' . quotemeta(__FILE__)) || __FILE__,
};
```

`quotemeta` will help to guard against possible shell metacharacter attacks in the file name.